# Blender .fbx to unity. textures not working

Tags: export, unity

So i`ve made a low poly tree and make the tree crown using an object info and a color ramp.
[image]

The problem is that when i`m exporting the model to unity the only texture that shows up is the log witch is a flat color, the crown goes grey.

[image]

I`m new to unity and exporting, so sorry if this is a simple question. And aalso sorry for the bad english